# Syncing Data with Dropbox Sync API

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to implement `Icloud` functionality(simultaneous sinking in different devices) in android through Dropbox SYNC API. I was able to read and write files to Dropbox. But what my issue is, I cannot listen for the changes to files in the Dropbox, even though I have implemented `DbxFile.Listener`. I am posting my sample code here. By this sample code what I am aiming is if I have modified a file in Dropbox, it should reflect in the application also. Also when running this application in two devices, file conflicts occurs in Dropbox folder. Could anyone tell me where I went wrong?? Any help in this regard is highly appreciable.

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private DbxAccountManager mDbxAcctMgr;

private static final String APP_KEY = "xxxxxxxxx";
private static final String APP_SECRET = "xxxxxxxxxx";
DbxFile testFile;
DbxFileSystem dbxFs;
DbxPath testPath;
Button btn;
EditText edit;
String contents;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    mDbxAcctMgr = DbxAccountManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext(),
            APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
    testPath = new DbxPath(DbxPath.ROOT, "mytext.txt");
    if (!mDbxAcctMgr.hasLinkedAccount()) {
        mDbxAcctMgr.startLink((Activity) this, 0);
    } else {
        try {
            dbxFs = DbxFileSystem
                    .forAccount(mDbxAcctMgr.getLinkedAccount());
            readFile(dbxFs);
        } catch (Unauthorized e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                dbxFs = DbxFileSystem.forAccount(mDbxAcctMgr
                        .getLinkedAccount());
                readFile(dbxFs);
            } catch (Unauthorized e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {

        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

private void readFile(DbxFileSystem dbxFs2) {

    try {
        try {
            if (dbxFs2.exists(testPath)) {

                testFile = dbxFs.open(testPath);
                testFile.addListener(listener);
                String contenString = testFile.readString().toString();
                showtoast(contenString);

            } else {
                testFile = dbxFs.create(testPath);
            }
        } catch (DbxException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } finally {
        testFile.close();
    }

}

private void showtoast(String msg) {

    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    contents = edit.getText().toString();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(contents)) {
        try {
            if (dbxFs.exists(testPath)) {
                new syncDropBox().execute();
            } else {
                dbxFs.create(testPath);
            }
        } catch (DbxException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            testFile.close();
        }
    }

}

private class syncDropBox extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    boolean result = false;

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... paramArrayOfParams) {
        try {
            dbxFs.syncNowAndWait();
            result = true;
        } catch (DbxException e) {
            result = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        if (result) {
            showtoast("sync succeed");
            try {
                testFile = dbxFs.open(testPath);
            } catch (DbxException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                testFile.writeString(contents);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            showtoast("sync failed");
        }
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}

DbxFile.Listener listener = new Listener() {

    @Override
    public void onFileChange(DbxFile paramDbxFile) {
        showtoast("file contents modified");

    }
};
```

}

Comment: how are you downloading files from dropbox? can you guide me

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're adding a listener but then immediately closing the file. Change listeners on individual files only fire while you have that file open.

You should keep the file open and use the `DbxFile.Listener` to watch for file changes and update the UI. To do that, you'll want to look at `DbxFile.getNewerStatus()`. Something like this:

```
@Override
public void on FileChange(DbxFile paramDbxFile) {
    if (paramDbxFile.getNewerStatus().isCached) {
        paramDbxFile.update();
        readFile(dbxFs);
    }
}
```

This, of course, means that if the user is in the middle of editing the text, and then the text is changed somewhere else, the user's edits will be lost (because `readFile` updates the `EditText`). You might want to instead tell the user that newer content is available and let them make the decision as to whether to pull in that new content or overwrite it with their own when they save.

Comment: Thanks @smarx, you have pointed out one of my mistakes.The real problem is I didn't get a call back to onFile changed listener. Is it because I am closing the file?? So what should I do?? open the file on onResume() and close it on onPause()??

Comment: You won't get notifications that the file has changed unless you keep it open. Yes, I would think that you should open it in `onResume` and close it in `onPause`.